# Is it acceptable to use a microscope in the office and not in the laboratory?

Tags: medicine, lab-management

I often see microscopes inside the office rooms of professors as well as other teaching members. They may not use them on daily basis but once in a while, or sometimes heavily used by a few of them. Some of them examine hospital slides received by that department from patients sputa to look for hazardous organisms (e.g. TB bacilli).

My question, according to the quality assurance standards of teaching laboratories, and from the safety point of view, is it acceptable to use microscopes inside offices instead of laboratory rooms? Is it acceptable to use them inside the office while wearing the casual clothes instead of the lab coat, and without gloves?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not unique to a medical school setting, but rather it applies to any non-laboratory setting.

Comment: This really depends on local laws: which country are you in?

Comment: In any scenario, the "use of a microscope" itself won't be a problem. Handling samples might be.

Comment: @jvb In some systems, a microscope might not be allowed in an office.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I don't really know enough, but I think this might be a *ethics/good practice* question and not a *legal* question.

Comment: This question is highly specific to your organization, location, and specific duties. I strongly recommend you take this question to your department administrators and get an answer from them.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is explicitly regulated by local laws and rules. It is nothing to do with ethics.

Comment: @tonysdg, the question was reworded as requested.

Comment: given the wide scope of Academia, it is hard to imagine this question is off-topic: a *microscope* is linked with *teaching* as well as with *laboratories*. Where does the difficulty come from?

Comment: @doctorate: My issue with this question is that it strikes me as a [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14486/342314) question. The main question you ask -- *is it acceptable to use microscopes inside offices instead of laboratory rooms?* -- doesn't really fall under the [topics you should ask about here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Yes, it affects academics in teaching hospitals -- but the heart of the question (and the best answers, IMO) has nothing to do with academia.

Comment: "look, there is this sample with a new virus similar to one that can be found in bats, I got it from the guys at the special Wuhan lab ..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see three main potential issues in the use of a microscope informally in an office, rather than in a laboratory environment:

- **Safety:** some samples might be potentially hazardous to a person handling them without laboratory protections.
- **Sample damage:** some samples may be vulnerable to contamination or damage through exposure to an office environment.
- **Ethics:** information on a patient or student subject may be exposed through informal handling of a sample.

If all three of these can be dealt with (e.g., through proper sample preparation and reasonable precautions against exposure of adverse information), then I see no reason that a microscope cannot be used in an informal office environment. I am not familiar with precautions around the particular samples you mention in your post, but many fixatives used with specimens are extremely effective and might well render samples quite inert.

Comment: good points to consider, as you pointed out in ethics, I would say privacy issues alone can be a good reason for *no-go*. Such practice would encourage others to do so, and some of the offices are shared among the staff members.

Comment: +1 Having had a microscope as a child, this answer strikes me as obvious.